# Knockout: Adding/Removing Select Dropdown Based On Value of Another Select Dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockout to build a user interface for the following situation:
- I have an array of items. Each item has an array of item details. 
- An item detail can be of one of two types: 'Type A' or 'Type B'. 
- If an item detail is of type of A, it can have one of two subtypes: 'Subtype A-1' and 'Subtype A-2'.
- If an item detail is of type of B, it does not have a subtype.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/casudeo/XscRT/2/)

I have the two questions/problems:

1. I'd like to add/remove the 'Detail Subtype' dropdown based on the value of the 'Detail Type' dropdown. For example, if the user selects 'Type B', I'd like to remove the 'Detail Subtype' dropdown. I also would like to set value of the underlying 'subtype' property to null. I played with the if binding but to no avail
2. In the addItemDetail method of the view model, how can I add a new item detail?

Comment: Wish I had enough reputation to down vote.  Kind of rude to delete the fiddle after you get your answer.  No one else can see the details to possibly learn from the answer(s) provided.

Comment: You should not remove the fiddle that was a part of the question. Your question is now incomplete and provided no valuable context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item details are an observable array containing regular objects that contain regular properties, not observables. You've already created a "pm.itemDetail" constructor function, so why don't you use that?

```
pm.Item = function(name, itemDetails) {
    // ...    
    var details = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < itemDetails.length; i++) {
        details.push( new pm.ItemDetail(itemDetails[i]) );
    }
    self.itemDetails = ko.observableArray(details);
};
```

I've updated the pm.ItemDetail function a bit:

```
pm.ItemDetail = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.type = ko.observable(data.type);
    self.subtype = ko.observable(data.subtype);
};
```

Now you're able to use the "visible" binding (the "if" binding hides the content of a DOM node, not the node itself):

```
data-bind="visible: type() == 1, ..."
```

---

To add a new item detail, just create an instance of "pm.ItemDetail" and push it to the itemDetails array of the currently selected item:

```
addItemDetail = function(item) {
    selectedItem().itemDetails.push(new pm.ItemDetail({
        name: "Please enter a name",
        type: 1,
        subtype: 1
    }));
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XscRT/6/

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow up question. In this fiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/casudeo/WLZrc/2/)), I added a saveItem method in which I am alerting the value of the subtype property. The subtype has a value regardless of what the value of type. Is there a way to set the subtype to null if type B is selected? Or, do I just make my saveItem smart enough to ignore subtype value if type = 1 before sending the save to the server.

Comment: You can do both things, but simply ignoring the value sometimes will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

1) You almost had it. You were missing the () in your if expression.

2) You can add an item detail like this ...

```
addItemDetail = function(item) {
    // what should be here to add a new detail to an item?
    selectedItem().itemDetails.push(new pm.ItemDetail());
};
```

I also modified how you add the item details through a new item. Notice the for loop in the fiddle below.

This fiddle has all of the above.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/FWFPV/

Comment: a) The fiddle is not working at all. b) What is the point in letting a constructor function return "this"? I mean, `new pm.ItemDetail()` returns "this" anyway, right?

Comment: sorry, i fixed the fiddle (typo)

Comment: b) its not needed in this case.